# open and edit files from dataset blob field

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I have files in a `TIBDataset` blob field.

I need to be able to open them and save all edits done to them.

I have tried to open files like this:

```cpp
String sFileName = "Test.txt";
((TBlobField*)(TDataset->FieldByName("FILE"))->SaveToFile(sFileName);
ShellExecute(0, L"open", sFileName.c_str(), L"", L"", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But I can't reliably delete made file, or save all the edits.

Is there a way to open a file from a blob field, or get a callback from closing an (external) file?

Comment: I personally add a Timer and every couple of seconds I check if the file has changed.

Comment: @MarcGuillot look at [`SHChangeNotifyRegister()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotifyregister) or [`ReadDirectoryChangesW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) for monitoring files for changes.

Comment: @Taavi if you use `ShellExecuteEx()` instead (or better, `CreateProcess()`), it can return a `HANDLE` that you can wait on to know when the spawned process has exited.  You can then re-load and delete the file you created as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to find a solution (not a perfect one) to my own problem.

I declared a `TStringList *slOpendFiles` in the header file and added all saved file names into it.

```
((TBlobField*)(TDataset->FieldByName("FILE"))->SaveToFile(sFileName);
slOpendFiles->Add(sFileName);`
```

And in the destructor, I tried to save and delete the files:

```
int iMaxFile = slOpendFiles->Count;
int iCurrFile = 0;
while (iCurrFile < iMaxFile){
    TDataset->Edit();
    ((TBlobField*)(TDataset->FieldByName("FILE")))->LoadFromFile(slOpendFiles->Strings[iCurrFile]);
    TDataset->Post();
    DeleteFile(slOpendFiles->Strings[iCurrFile]);
    iCurrFile++;
}
```

NP! The delete doesn't work with some files if they are opened.

Comment: "*The delete doesn't work with some files if they are opened*" - of course not. You can't delete a file that is in use, unless the code that is using the file explicitly specifies `DELETE` sharing rights when opening the file. What you can try doing instead is open each file yourself first, specifying `READ`/`WRITE` sharing rights and the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag, and then leave the files open until you are done using them, or at least until someone else has opened them. The files will delete themselves automatically once everyone has closed their handles to them.